# How to re-word my alleged "snarky" comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, quality-improvement

A few minutes back, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41703038/2173917) question was posted.

As the content in discussion was not a standard one as per the language tag, I left a comment under the question:

> [*What is `isnumber`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703038/why-does-isnumber-function-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char?noredirect=1#comment70601902_41703038)

and then, *with a smiley at the end*,

> [*With all due respect, from a 6+ year user, we can expect a better written question, don't we? :)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703038/why-does-isnumber-function-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char?noredirect=1#comment70601999_41703038)

However, I got a response from OP mentioning

> *instead of the snarky comment. You should have asked the compiler/OS to be added to the question which would reduce the noise*

Now I'm here trying to improve my language competency. Is there a better way this comment would have been written by me?

Comment: @leaf I also thought so, but then, I am not a native speaker and neither we are here to offend anyone by mistake, so thought of asking.

Comment: What is more troubling is that the question, refering to a function no-one can positively identify, is still not closed as unclear, and received two well upvoted answers.

Comment: Adding a smiley at the end of a snarky comment does not make your comment less snarky; it just adds more snark :).

Comment: @Tunaki Just to let you know, _I did my part_. :)

Comment: With all due respect, from a 2+ year user, we can expect a better written question, don't we? :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan OK, but I did not mean to snarky, if that's what you're wondering. How do I put it then?

Comment: Without mentioning something specific to improve about the question, your comment basically just says "your question is bad." which isn't particularly useful and invites additional off-topic comments, which it got. Rephrasing it won't change that.

Comment: It looks like the OP already told you how to be less snarky in their reply.

Comment: @BSMP but is not that what I asked in my very first comment?

Comment: *letting the use know they need to add more info* @leaf - No it doesn't, it just says the question should be written better. It does not say that the problem with the question is that information is missing.

Comment: @BSMP but I don't have any idea about the topic in question there? How do I know that is a different system function? How do I know that is not something "rolling-my-own-function" API? That was the thought process behind that comment, anyway. Did not mean to offend anybody.

Comment: No problem here.  I'd flag the question asking for a comment cleanup because they don't serve any purpose now except for causing a distraction.

Comment: Disregarding the content, though, "don't we?" doesn't really follow "we can..." properly. I think it should either be "we do... don't we?" or "we can... can't we?" But this comment has nothing to do with snarkiness, so please feel free to flag it as not constructive. ;)

Comment: How do you recognize the problems with that question, but not with your comment? They're the same problems.

Comment: The first comment was fine—it commented on the *substance* of the post. The second comment was not, because it commented on the *user* who posted it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no guarantees when you write comments. The most benign one can be seen as a grave insult and one that may seem insulting to one person may appear benign to another.

This being said... This was the comment (emphasis added):

> With all due respect, **from a 6+ year user**, we can expect a better written question, don't we? :)

In other words, "you're inadequate".

I suggest focusing on the question. There's is (again) no guarantee that focusing on the question *will* avert a negative reaction. Still, if you do focus on the question, then the author of the question has to make the jump from "this person found my question inadequate" to "this person found me inadequate". Whereas if you focus on the person with your comment, then they don't have to make the jump because the comment itself focused on them.

And when focusing on the question it is good to provide an observation of substance. It does not mean engaging in a dissertation about writing questions but if we remove the user aspect from your comment it boils down to saying the question is bad without saying how exactly. I'd say provide some specific aspect that should be fixed, or just downvote and vote-to-close without a comment if it is so atrocious that a comment won't suffice.

Answer (score 4):

It is completely useless comment - feel free to delete it. There is no way to improve it as it does not ask for clarifications nor adds details.

If you see similar comments from others - flag as "too chatty" and move on.
For this particular post you could have downvoted due to lack of research or/and add comment asking to add whatever you think is missing.

Note: I personally think [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703038/why-does-isnumber-function-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char?noredirect=1#comment70601902_41703038) is not that awful - not many people aware about other digits or numeral characters in Unicode... But definitely showing more research would not hurt. Answer obviously should be one character - [㊷](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/32b7/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. two things, A) I would like to write a comment instead which _asks for clarification_ B) IMHO, adding link to help center to an experienced user is not likely to help much either. So how should I put my comment exactly?

Comment: Also, I did DV and VTC, both.

Comment: Just asking, are you referring to a different question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703038/why-does-isnumber-function-take-a-int-instead-of-a-char - in current state with link to the doc it is more reasonable... Commenting about "`isnumber` is not in standard library - make sure to add link to doc/code, without it it is very unclear/low quality" would be definitely more constructive.

Comment: OK, sure, I'll remember that.